# How can I change Excel 2007 shortcuts from foreign to English?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a copy of Excel 2007 that happens to be in Brazilian Portuguese. For me it's great since I'm in Brazil but there is a catch.

All the English shortcuts I'm used to, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for saving, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> for bold etc. are also translated.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> it thinks I want to underline the text.

How do I change the shortcuts to the English default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to simply recreate the shortcuts as macros :

1. Go to the Developer tab and press Record Macro
2. Fill the macro's description and shortcut key, and set its placement in "Personal Macro Workbook" and press OK
3. Do your action
4. Go to the Developer tab and press Stop recording.

The Personal Macro Workbook is a hidden workbook that opens when you start Excel. The code you copy in this workbook is available in all workbooks you have opened in Excel.

More info in:
[How to Create Custom Keyboard Shortcuts in Excel 2007?](http://www.lytebyte.com/2008/10/06/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-2007/)
[How do I create a PERSONAL.XLS](http://www.rondebruin.nl/personal.htm)

Comment: This aproach works. But I have to create macros for each and every single shortcut I want to change. I wish there is a way of justing changing the shortcuts not creating macros.

Comment: I didn't find any other way of changing the keyboard mapping for Excel.

Comment: Since no one else gave another possibility. I'll assume that's the only way to do it. Thanks @harrymc!